# How to skip text at the left side of a line but recognise it at the end of that line

Tags: antlr4

I'm new to ANTLR4 and like to parse OCR-ed invoices.

In my grammar I have parser rules:

```
sometext factor% value NEWLINE
factor: INT;
value: FLOAT;
```

for example:

```
any text 10% 123.45 \r
```

`"any text"` can contain really any text, the line could read for example:
`"some text 7% to 45.55 some text 10% 123.45 \r"`

I have to match `"some text 7% to 45.55 some text" to "sometext"`, `"10"` for `"factor"` and `"123.45"` to `"value"`.

My question is:

How can I do this, i.e. how do I prevent ANTLR to match "7" to "factor" ...

Comment: To do this, you have to add rules for everything (lexer rules for white space, any character, PERCENT, FLOAT, INT, where order is important; parser rules for lines, and a non-greedy match of any prefix in a line).  `grammar g; lines : line* EOF; line: .*? factor '%' value NEWLINE; factor: INT; value: FLOAT; INT : [0-9]+; FLOAT : [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]+; PERCENT: '%'; NEWLINE: [\r\n]+; WS : [ \t]+ -> skip; ANY: .;`

Comment: Another approach could be to remove the text parts that are not interesting in a preprocessing step and feed only the remaining text to the parser.